# Any book about math in game design?

Tags: game-design, mathematics, books

Game designers need math as one of their tools for designing game, unfortunately I can't find one book concentrate on this topic. I know there's math book about game programmer, but designer need different math sub-branch knowledge like probability, game theory etc. And most important is examples tell us how to use these math knowledge as our powerful tools. Is there some books or articles available talk about this topic? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a really helpful wiki: http://math2033.uark.edu/wiki/index.php/Game_Theory.

I haven't read this, but it looks promising: http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/229281.Game_Theory

A lot of colleges offer free online course material. [Here's one from Yale.](http://oyc.yale.edu/economics/econ-159)

Comment: The OP specifically asked for math resources on game theory relevant to a designer vs those that are relevant to a programmer.  The downvotes on this answer are clearly from people that did not grasp the question.